# Use Gmap in Offline Mode

Tags: c#, gmap.net

I developed an Application and use GMAP.net in c# windows Form. When The system is Connect to Internet the Application work  successfully but I want to work with Gmap in offline mode. so I use GMap.NETChacher-master (link:https://github.com/williamwdu/GMap.NETChacher) and save "Data.gmdb" in location "E:\test\TileDBv5\en".
Now in Form_load I write this Code:

```
GMaps.Instance.Mode = AccessMode.CacheOnly;
        gMapControl1.CacheLocation = @"E:\test\TileDBv5\en";
        gMapControl1.MapProvider = GMap.NET.MapProviders.OpenStreetMapProvider.Instance;
        gMapControl1.ShowCenter = false;
        gMapControl1.Zoom = 11;
        gMapControl1.Position = new PointLatLng(32, 51);
```

But When the project load, The map not show and the error show is: "Exceptio. no data in local Tile cache". please help me...